# Windows Server: load balancing to multiple ports in the same server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-service

Context: we develop a windows service that handles communication with devices using a proprietary protocol under TCP.

Question: How can I setup multiple instances if this windows service listening on distinct ports (e.g. 3001,3002,3003) and have a single port (e.g. 3000) forwarding traffic (or load-balancing) between this instances?

We use a Windows Server 2008 R2. I have found solutions for load balancing multiple servers using NLB, but I was unable to configure the same for a single server and multiple ports.

Why? Transparent deploys using a single server, evaluate the stability of a release before using it with all clients, and the services seems to perform better in a 3 instances 1k clients per instance than 1 instance 3k clients.

Comment: I tried to configure NLB, but it seems to need another machine to create a cluster, not balancing in a single machine. Right now I am trying to configure ngnix to balance tcp connections on windows.

Comment: The NGINX solution will probably be a good option. On Windows you're fairly limited with these kinds of things, but on Linux there's *lots* of choice.

Comment: @GregL, thanks a lot. One more question, is there a specific name for this "port load balancing" I am trying to achieve? It seems to be something in between load balancing and reverse proxy.

Comment: I think you want TCP load balancing or TCP reverse proxying.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using 3 different ip addresses pointing to 3 instances of your service on the same server? That'll give you 3 ip stacks and likely the performance you need. You can also try to tune the TCP stack by adapting some of the default system parameters. Some explanation on what parameters there are and what they do can be found here https://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10438.aspx